# Three states continuous animation (MotionLayout)

Tags: android, animation, transition, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to make a continuous animation from the `initial` state up to the `end` state.

[image: Transition graph]

The transition from `initial` to `start` should be instant, so I set `app:clickAction="jumpToEnd"` on the `OnClick` handler.

The transition from `start` to `end` should automatically play after the previous transition, so I set `app:autoTransition="animateToEnd"`. However, this does not happen. The overall animation is stuck in the `start` state and does not play further.

If I remove the `jumpToEnd` from the `initial -> start` handler, the animation continues with the `start -> end` transition, which makes me think that it is not a problem with the `ConstraintSet`s of the states.

How can I implement the desired behaviour, i.e. `initial  -jumpOnClick->  start  -automaticallyAnimate->  end`?

Comment: Have you found a solution for it friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had been fixed on [Constraintlayout-v2.0.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout?hl=en#constraintlayout-2.0.2).

Bug Fixes

- ...
- jump to end was broken in MotionLayout in some situations (chaining transitions)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to auto animations you must set easy inout in sensxml file layout indicator and no need add constraint layout in main only need in start and end layouts

Comment: I need a solution for Motion Layout. I don’t think your answer is related.

Comment: @deniskrr so i tell you i have same problam there is one method in your motionlayout sens xml call layout indicator =easyinout it must set for auto anim work, than remove  constraintlayout in your mainlayout only set your views like button... than check your start and end layout have constraint layout  it must be, im test this with  constraint layout v2.0.0 beta 2